# Which of the following are true..

Tags: general-topology

Let $:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}^3$ be given by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(e^{x_1}cosx_1,e^{x_2}sinx_1,2x_1-cosx_3)$. consider $E=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \Bbb{R}^3$: there exists an open subset $U$ around $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $f|_U$ is an open map}. Then which of the following are true?

- $E=\Bbb{R}^3$
- $E$ is countable
- $E$ is not countable but not $\Bbb{R}^3$
- $\{(x_1,x_2,\frac{\pi}{2}:x_1,x_2\in \Bbb{R}\}$ is a proper subset of $E$.

I studied Munkres topology, Armstrong topology. But I didn't find such type of problems. I don't have any idea to solve this problem.
Any hint.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what is an open map? And, do you know of some easy criteria that guarantee that a map is open (Think of inverse function theorem for example)?